# What does 'They hurried by him' mean in context?

Tags: meaning

What does 'They hurried by him' mean in context? Who are 'they'?

> "I will be back before dark," he told her harshly and, turning from her, he strode away towards the ruined sillhouette of the Colesberg kopje which stood out starkly, even through the stinking miasma of smoke and dust that hovered over the camp. Zouga might have been a wraith, a thing of air, invisible to human eyes. **They hurried by him on the narrow track, or remained stooped over mill and cradle while he passed**, without an inclination of head or even a casual glance, an entire community living for one thing only, completely absorbed and obsessed.

**Source**: Wilbur Smith's adventure novel, *Men of Men: The Ballantyne*

Comment: It's impossible to know without more context. People of some sort.

Comment: Only you have the context.

Comment: I can not give more limit.

Comment: You are supposed to add the context to the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'They' are the inhabitants of the diamond-diggers' camp, 'the kopje-wallowers' previously mentioned, 'the entire community living for one thing [diamonds] only'. These are the people who hurried by [past] him on the narrow track. This is Wilbur Smith's adventure novel, "Men of Men: The Ballantyne". [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mRNDDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT19&lpg=PT19&dq=Zouga%20might%20have%20been%20a%20wraith,%20a%20thing%20of%20air,%20invisible%20to%20human%20eyes.&source=bl&ots=5hjSDASIoS&sig=SIUzvYRcHAZkfeyuHnduA8qzDxY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivj_DYtprdAhXlIMAKHSrHBYsQ6AEwAHoECBwQAQ#v=onepage&q=Zouga%20might%20have%20been%20a%20wraith%2C%20a%20thing%20of%20air%2C%20invisible%20to%20human%20eyes.&f=false)

Comment: Well, there it is. So there was an antecedent. Sounds like a good book.

Comment: @Lambie "Sounds like a good book." - If you like that sort of thing.

Comment: You forgot to explain to hurry by them.